Operation not permitted installing python package
I used the VS Code terminal and tried to install flask in my virtual environment.
(.venv) neo@Air test % python -m pip install flask

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "/Users/neo/Downloads/test/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/__main__.py", line 8, in <module>
    if sys.path[0] in ("", os.getcwd()):
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^
PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted

Following the official VS code guide to install flask in the virtual environment, I did everything correct.
Solution: I fixed it. Allow full disk access for VS Code.
